# Check if two consts are empty

Tags: c++, blackberry-10

I'm kind of new to the C++ scene so I'm wondering how I'd verify both fields have some text entered, here's the current code which is only verifying one field

```
void App::requestLogin(const QString &email, const QString &password) {
    if (m_active)
        return;

    //how can I do both password and email here????
    const QStringList list = email.split(QRegExp("\\s+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        m_errorMessage = "please complete both fields";
        m_error = true;
        emit statusChanged();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want to achieve? If "both are empty" or "if either is empty"?

Comment: If both are empty please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you mean, but this is my wild guess based on your error message. You do not even need a regex for this. Even if you needed, you should use QRegularExpression rather than the much slower QRegExp.

```
void App::requestLogin(const QString &email, const QString &password) {
    if (m_active)
        return;

    ...

    if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
        m_errorMessage = "please complete both fields";
        m_error = true;
        emit statusChanged();
        return;
    }
}
```

This operation is also more logical than `&&` as you wrote in your comment because usually you need to supply both email *and* password. Basically the condition will meet if either of those meets. That means if any of the input fields kept empty, you will raise the error which seems a reasonable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
if (list.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty())
```

I'm not sure why you are "splitting" the email. If it's just an email address used for login purposes, you should be able to do `email.isEmpty()` rather than using the regexp splitting.